# How can I determine if process is user program or simply a process

Tags: windows, kernel, device-driver

When I open task manager I see all processes that are running on the machine.

I am wondering is it possible, at the **kernel level** (*in a device driver*) to differentiate between a **system level process** (*such as a service*) and an **user level application** (*such as 'notepad'*) that are running for a *specific* user?

More elaboration: On windows 7, there is a tab for "applications" and a tab for "processes" ... I want the same list as the "applications" tab, only obtained at the device driver level

I have C# code that gets all processes..

```
       Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
```

I need to translate that down into a device driver and return only the applications

Comment: Are you asking how to tell what account a process is running in?  Every process is a process, and every process runs with the credentials of some account.  Note that distinguishing based on account does not match the "usual" definition of application, which involves creation of visible windows.

Comment: no, The "account" will contain both system level processes and user level processes -- what I am asking: is it possible at the "kernel level" to distinguish between a system level process, (such as a service) and a user level process, such as an application (eg Notepad).

Comment: All the processes you are talking about are user-mode, none are kernel-mode.  Many services can be distinguished by account, e.g. LOCAL_SERVICE, NETWORK_SERVICE, or even SYSTEM.  And all services controlled by the service manager can be distinguished somehow (Task Manager shows PID for each service).  However, there are other background processes which are not services and you may not wish to include in the list of applications.  What is the exact rule you wish to use?

Comment: Open task manager... there is a tab for "applications" and a tab for "processes" (under windows 7 anyway) ... I want the same list as the "applications" tab.

Comment: Ok, edit your question to say that (although on 8.1 I see one tab "Processes" and the list is grouped into "Apps" and "Background Processes" and "Windows Processes")

Comment: Have you seen this blog article by Raymond Chen?  [How does Task Manager categorize processes as App, Background Process, or Windows Process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606)

Comment: Just read it... the author's comment 'That's all. Nothing fancy. And completely arbitrary'  ... if it was completely 'arbitrary' then it would be completely random each time the task manager comes up... Pretty useless article IMHO.

Comment: Raymond is saying the rules are arbitrary, in the sense that there are many possible rules for "this is an application and that is not" and they just picked one that's good enough.  But they still can be (and are) applied consistently.  If you find that article (written by a Microsoft employee with direct access to the Task Manager source code) useless, then your task is hopeless.

Comment: Just because he is an MS employee... doesn't mean he has access to code... I ~was~ an MS employee that had access to code to a certain application ... but not ALL code within the company... but I get the "rules are arbitrary" comment...

Comment: Not all MS employees have access to Windows code, but I was making a specific claim that Raymond Chen (is or has been) one of the ones who does.  I suppose I could just have said "someone who's seen the Task Manager code" without mentioning Microsoft, but there are also a lot of people outside MS with read access to Windows code.  On the other hand, the actual relevant part is that Raymond understands that code so much better than most others who have seen it.

Comment: maybe you could ask him how to get applications at the driver level ?

Comment: Now that is reasonable for a StackOverflow question.  I suggest just editing this one to include a clear problem statement, now that you have a defining rule ("Same as Task Manager 'Apps' list on the Processes tab"), and to include the background information ("In user-mode, here's how it is done" + link to Old New Thing) -- even better if you write a quick test that works in user mode and can include your code --- and then you can ask how to do that from a kernel driver.

Comment: The unfortunate thing is that it is probably very difficult -- Win32 windows are managed by USER32.DLL, not the kernel.  And what about Metro/Modern/Windows Store GUI apps? (not applicable to Windows 7, but most of your customers probably are not still on Windows 7)

Comment: The window manager is in the win32k[base,full].sys driver, and accessed in user mode via `NtUser[]` system calls, either from user32.dll (older versions) or win32u.dll (Windows 10). This uses session space and memory shared with user mode. Plus you'd have to handle console apps. Other than the nominal owner of the console window (usually the application that allocated it), the list of associated processes is in conhost.exe and requires attaching to call `GetConsoleProcessList`. Maybe Task Manager has a back door to this information.

Comment: hmmm sounds like I am stuck with GetProcesses... and doing my own filtering... Thanks all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion under my question, the answer is:

```
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Then doing my own filtering to see if the process has a window or not.
Thanks everybody !